# Get the longest substring from a string which is passed in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, for-loop

I want to pass in a string into a method e.g. "abbcccdef" and want it to return the longest substring. in this case it would be "ccc". Someone please help me with code that would help me solve this issue. I would like something basic that would allow a beginner to understand easily. This is what i have so far but it doesnt seem to work:

Many Thanks

```
public String getLongestSubstring(String s) {

        int [] length = new int [s.length()];
        String longestString = "";
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            char c = s.charAt(0);
            for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
                for (int j=0;j<s.length();j++) {
                    if (c==s.charAt(j)) {
                        length [i]++;
                    } else {
                        c = s.charAt(j);
                        i++;
                    }
                }

            }
            return longestString;
        }
        else
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: 'Doesn't seem to work'? What does it do? Have you used a debugger? A few strategic print statements?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this and I found and fixed one error already, but I think I've covered all the bases now. One limitation you didn't elaborate on in your question was the case in which there are two substrings of equal, longest length. i.e. abbbcccdef, I just return the first.

```
public String getLongestSubstring(String s)
{
    if (s.length() == 0) return null;

    //We need some data to start with.
    char currentChar = s.charAt(0);
    String longestString = "" + currentChar;
    String runningString = "" + currentChar;
    int currentLongestLength = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        //Check the current char, is it the same?
        if (s.charAt(i) == currentChar)
        {
            runningString = runningString + currentChar;
            //Have we beaten our previous record.
            if (runningString.length() > longestString.length())
            {
                //Increase the record.
                currentLongestLength++;
                longestString = runningString;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            runningString = "" + s.charAt(i); 
        }
    }
    return longestString;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. I thought of that scenario too. What would i have to do if i wanted to return both the equal substrings as two different substrings? Thanks again

Comment: I'd probably create a map of `Map<String, Integer>` where string is the substring and the Integer is the lengths of those strings, find the max of those lengths. Then return an array of Strings with lengths equal to max.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it was! =]

Comment: The runningString = s.charAt(i);  doesnt work. The IDE says it needs to be changed to type char but i gues we have to leave it as string. how do we do that?

Comment: I fixed that problem. Have a look at the edit

Answer (score 1):

Follow the bellow mentioned algorithm  [sub-string sequence](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I implemented to find a longest SubString from a String.

```
public class LongestString {    

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        System.out.println("Longest Substring is " + getLongestSubstring("abbcccdf"));
    }

    public static String getLongestSubstring(String s) {
            int length = 1;

        String longestString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.append(s.charAt(i));

            for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    str.append(s.charAt(j));
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (length < str.length()) {
                length = str.length();
                longestString = str.toString();
            }

        }
        return longestString;
    }
}
```

**Test it:** http://ideone.com/JM904Y

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getLongestSubString(String source) {

    StringBuilder longestStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(source.length());
    String longestString = "";

    for(int i=0; i<source.length(); i++) {

        if(longestStringBuilder.toString().contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(i)))) {

            if(longestString.length() < longestStringBuilder.toString().length()) {
                longestString = longestStringBuilder.toString();
            }

            longestStringBuilder.setLength(0);
        }

        longestStringBuilder.append(source.charAt(i));

    }

    if(longestString.length() < longestStringBuilder.toString().length()) {
        longestString = longestStringBuilder.toString();
    }

    return longestString;
}
```